# how do I print the todo value to the console from an object in an array

Tags: javascript

I tried printing out todo values to the console

```
let newArray= [
{id:248506.45824805673, todo:"todo 1"},
{id:971916.6755153723, todo:"todo 2"}
```

]
console.log(newArray[0].todo)

When I try outputting this to the console I get "undefine"

Comment: `newArray[0].todo`

Comment: You seem to have trouble with formatting. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: its working well with your code, please create [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer indexes to access array elements.

```js
let newArray= [ 
  {id:248506.45824805673, todo:"Todo 1"}
];
console.log(newArray[0].todo);
```

In case you want to print all todo values in the array, use a `for` loop:

```js
let newArray = [{
    id: 248506.45824805673,
    todo: "todo 1"
  },
  {
    id: 971916.6755153723,
    todo: "todo 2"
  }
];
for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(newArray[i].todo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Please how do I get the values of todo from the object in the array giving that I  have a continuous list of todos. I was trying to get the list of todo to perform a conditional check on it.